# Trying to create a search form that show the image

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
mysql_connect("x","y","z!") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("x") or die("Could not connect");

$output = '';
// Collect 
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uni_slider WHERE slider_name LIKE '%$searchq%' OR slider_image LIKE '%$searchq%' OR slider_price LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("Could not search");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0){
        $output = 'There was no such results';
    }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                $name = $row['slider_name'];
                $image = $row['slider_image'];
                $price = $row['slider_price'];


                $output .= '<div class="output">'?><img src="/upload/<?php echo $row['slider_image'];?>"><?php <br/> '.$name.' <br/> '.$price.' <font color="#2ecc71">$</font><br/></div>;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This is my code, now the output part doesnt work. If I make the code like this

`$output .= '<div class="output> '.$image.' <br/> '.$name.' <br/> '.$price.' <font color="#2ecc71">$</font><br/></div>';`

It only shows me the image file name, not the image.

I've tried `"> but it gives me erros, any help ? Thanks

---

Comment: at `"> i was taking about img src=""

Answer (score -1):

Extremely simple, you forgot the close `output`  It should be `<div class="output">`  then change the `/upload/` to a symbolic link inside the web root directory, you cannot just put `/something` as apache will not be able to process it.   if you say ln -s /upload uploadlink that could work if you have shell access

Comment: Yes but that is not my question. How do I make it to show the actual image not the image file name.

Comment: I get "26183_banner2.jpg" not the actual image

Comment: Well because you had layered issues, it wouldn't have worked.  Now the next issue is you are trying to go to the upload directory from a `/`, you can't do that in webservers.  You need to make a symbolic link inside the directory and then link it.  Do you have access to the shell?

Comment: Yes I do have access